# An isometry from $[0, \infty)$ to $[0, \infty)$ which is not a homeomorphism.

Tags: general-topology

I proved that every isometry is a homeomorphism but there is a question

"find an isometry from $[0, \infty)$ to $[0, \infty)$ which is not a homeomorphism."

Am I do something wrong?

Any suggestion is valuable for me.

Comment: What is the definition of isometry in use? If it doesn't include surjectivity, an isometry need not be a homeomorphism. An isometry is always an embedding, however.

Comment: $(X,d)$ is metric space, a function $f: X-->X$  is  called isometry if $d(x,y)= d(f(x),f(y)) $ for all $x,y$ in $X$

Comment: Then look at your proof that an isometry is a homeomorphism and find the place where you inadvertently slipped in a surjectivity asumption.

Comment: @DanielFischer thanks a lot!

Answer (score 3):

$$[0,\infty)\to[0,\infty),\quad x\mapsto x+1$$
(Homeomorphisms are in particular surjective.)